# How to flag a comment in GitHub Issue for moderation (spam, misinformation, hate speech)

Tags: github, spam-prevention, github-issues

On GitHub, how can I flag a comment in a project issue as spam, misinformation, hate speech, etc?

I came across a comment in a GitHub issue recently that was not only completely off-topic, but also aggressive and attempting to spread misinformation.

As with most other Web-2.0 websites, I expected there to be some way to click the hamburger menu on the comment and "flag" it. And I'd expect that a "flagged" message would alert a content moderator about the problematic content. And I would expect that, if several users flagged the same content, then it would be automatically removed unless a moderator manually approved it.

Previously, I've also encountered many "locked" issues on GitHub, which stifles collaboration. When I asked the repo maintainer why they locked old issues, they said it was done to ease the burden of having to moderate spam on old issues.

Am I missing something? Where is the `flag comment` button in GitHub issues?

Comment: See also https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/40409

Comment: See also https://docs.github.com/en/discussions/managing-discussions-for-your-community/moderating-discussions

Comment: On repositories you maintain, you have access to "Delete" and "Report Content," the latter which (should) filter up to GitHub support. Are you referring to "how to flag material" on repositories where you are not a collaborator?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a way that anyone with a GitHub account can flag content. And not just to report it to the GitHub support, but also to the repository owner for more decentralized moderation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report the user, not the comment.

As far as I know, it's not possible to flag a specific comment on a GitHub issue. Instead, just click on the user then click the `Report` button on their user profile.

Comment: Huh. Silly, I guess, but I'll give it a try. A repository I tend to participate has been invaded by all sorts of spammers/scammers. The actual owners are away-ish (they have other priorities) and not taking good care of the repository; but it has some activity, enough for spammers/scammers become interested...